# How to duplicate a pandas dataframe to match other dataframe's length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following dataframes:

df1:

```
a    
10.
20.
30.
40.
50.
60.
70.
80.
90.
100.
110.
120.
```

df2:

```
b
1.
2.
```

df3:

```
b
1.
2.
3.
```

Knowing `len(df1.values) % len(df2.values) == 0`, I want to divide each element of `df1` by each element of `df2`, after having repeated `df2` as many times as needed to fit `df1`1's length, meaning in this case

result(df1, df2):

```
a    
10.
10.
30.
20.
50.
30.
70.
40.
90.
50.
110.
60.
```

result(df1, df3):

```
a    
10.
10.
10.
40.
25.
20.
70.
40.
30.
100.
55.
40.
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this, preferably without going through numpy?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid going through Numpy?

Comment: My thinking is, if this can be done with pure pandas, then why go to numpy and back

Comment: **1.** If you've imported Pandas then you've already imported Numpy.  **2.** In order to perform the division, you have to ignore the native Pandas index objects because they do not align.  This implies that you need to divide by either a numpy array or a deliberately constructed Pandas.Series in which you'd need to populate with a Numpy array.  My point is, in this case, it is far more elegant and performant to utilize a simple Numpy solution rather than a convoluted one in an effort to avoid Numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html), where the new array will be filled with copies of the original until it fits the specified length:

```
df1['a'] /= np.resize(df2.b.values, df1.shape[0])

      a
0    10.0
1    10.0
2    30.0
3    20.0
4    50.0
5    30.0
6    70.0
7    40.0
8    90.0
9    50.0
10  110.0
11   60.0
```

---

Or using [`pd.np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df1['a'] /= pd.np.tile(df2.b, df1.shape[0]//df2.shape[0])
```

Comment: @QuangHoang from OP "Knowing `len(df1.values) % len(df2.values) == 0`"

Comment: Actually having an error in this case is good for me, but would like to know how not to get an error just for knowledge sake

Comment: seems to be wokring fine with `np.resize` @QuangHoang

Comment: @Gulzar let me know if its woking for you with the update

Comment: `pd.np` is the same `numpy` you'd import via `import numpy as np`.  So, when you do import Numpy after importing pandas, you aren't doing any additional work as it is already imported.  There is no additional overhead to import Numpy after having imported Pandas.  Please don't assume that there is a time or memory advantage of not importing Numpy.  The only thing you save is 19 characters.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @piRSquared :) Wasn't assuminng so, was just basing it on the fact that OP wants to avoid `numpy`, for the rest I fully agree

Comment: I understand.  I wrote an equally grumpy old man comment on OP question (-:

Answer (score 2):

I will do

```
n=len(df1)//len(df2)
df1.a/np.tile(df2.b,n+1)[:len(df1)]
Out[871]: 
0      10.0
1      10.0
2      30.0
3      20.0
4      50.0
5      30.0
6      70.0
7      40.0
8      90.0
9      50.0
10    110.0
11     60.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```